# SMTP Clients rejected with Citadel

Tags: linux, email, smtp

I setup a Citadel Mail Server on a RPI 3B+. I have DNS setup, port forwarding, and port open on firewall. When I enter through the webmail portal, I can send and receive mail just fine. The issue that I am having is with mail clients.

I can use IMAP and POP just fine to receive mail with my credentials just fine also.

Whenever I try to send mail using a client (tried a couple different ones), it fails on sending. Right now, I am not using SSL until I get it working on the basic port. The devices I am trying are local devices that do not pass a firewall. With sender authentication turned on, it always says invalid login even though the same login works for IMAP and POP. Turned off it says it requires a login.

For some reason it rejects logins to send mail even if they are a valid user on the system. Works 100% though with the same user on the webmail portal.

Any ideas on how to get this working?
Let me know if more info is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not fully an answer, but since nobody is responding to this I will add the conclusion I got to when doing more research. Uninstall Citadel and find a tutorial for Postfix and Dovecot for RPI. I have it mostly working, but have a bit of work to do with StartTLS.

Answer (score -1):

I am right there with you. I have an issue where I am attempting to attach an Outlook client to the server and it will validate IMAP just fine - but continues to blow errors on the SMTP portion on port 465. It's the same account, same password - but nothing I try - no conflicts with any ports etc seem to work.

I give up - especially since the documentation is all over the place - took a couple hours to figure out that

1 - You NEED to use letsencrypt to generate certs. Using self signed gives you unpredictable results. Oh and you need to put them in the right place - and not /etc/ssl/citadel. It goes into the /usr area.

2 - the locations of where it puts things are a haphazard jumble of google-fu to try and find - and half the documentation links are dead so....

I'm with you - Since I've learned what I need for DNS entries with my host such as proper A records, MX records and such, setting up signed auth certs with the lets encrypt cert bot etc, I could have used the several hours wasted on Citadel and setup a real stack with Postfix and Dovecot.